# How to use "OR" in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have different response in different scopes and I need to check in both the scopes for the values in ng-repeat.

For Example:

```
$scope.abc = data;
$scope.def = data;

<div ng-repeat = result in abc || mresult in def></div>
```

But the ng-repeat is failing may be OR is not working, is there any way to handle this.

Comment: could `$scope.abc` and `$scope.def` contain data simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="result in abc || def">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either have 2 `ngRepeat`s:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in abc"></div>
<div ng-repeat="result in def"></div>
```

Or concatenate the arrays:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in abc.concat(def)"></div>
```